# Put 2 Links on Background Image HTML Mail Message

Tags: javascript, html, image, html-email

I need two pages to be open at once when the user clicks on an image that is being sent in an email message.

I tried to use ***window.open*** but when the message is sent to the recipient the link on the image does not work.

Could you help me or tell me a better way to make this possible??

The code:

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.g1.com.br');"><img width="500" align="center" src="img_1"></a>
```

Comment: Almost all mail clients remove/disable javascript, so you're onclick methods won't work. Additionally, the `src` of the image needs to be absolute (ie: http://www.example.com/image.jpg)

Comment: Thanx for the response, Samuel!! The **src** is only one example!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within email app, **it's not possible**. As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) mentioned above, all of the email consumption software, including Outlook, webmail and iPhone native email app will block your JavaScript in the message.

However, in theory, the result could be achieved using an **intermediary landing page**, which would perform the all the JS you need, opening two tabs.

I once had a similar project where we implemented intermediary landing page that sniffed the user agent and redirected to the deep-linked mobile website or a different desktop landing page. For example, you would link to your landing page like:

```
http://yourlandingpage.com?tab1toopen=http://page1.com&tab2toopen=http://page2.com
```

This raises new issues around:
* URL tracking (and automating encoding and/or optional URL shortening and admin of all of this),
* URL length (which is limited on Windows desktop Outlook clients),
* security of that landing page (lander should sanitize the strings, maybe even do some secret hand-shaking via unique encrypted var), and,
* can it sustain the heavy traffic (which is larger problem that it appears if you work with big brands).

Answer (score 0):

Due to major security issues, scripting is not available in emails.  Many clients will strip the scripting completely while others can mark it as spam or block it entirely.

Your best bet would be to have it link to a static landing page that then runs a script to open the two windows for you.

- http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/jsemail.htm

Some other good sources on what is allowed and not allowed in HTML email:

http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email
http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/common-html-mistakes
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/

Comment: I didn't say it was a comprehensive solution, only the best bet when coming via an HTML email. If you have a better solution, please share.

Comment: I do not know what to do or where to look for alternatives to make it happen ...
I thought that the inline script would work... :(

Comment: you would need to direct it more onto a landing page. As Quentin so nicely pointed out, popup blockers will make it difficult even there, but there is no alternative option directly inside the email.

Comment: @Gortonington I would upvote this again if I could. What the OP is asking is simply not possible, and answering as such is a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank" onclick="DoThis();"><img width="500" align="center" src="img_1"></a>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoThis() {
window.open('http://www.foo.com', _blank);  //open link 1 in new tab
window.open('http://www.g1.com.br', _blank); //open link 2 in new tab
}
</script>
```

Comment: I will try right now, @Korgrue!!
I dont know if this will work on my html mail, but i wanna try!!!!

Comment: Inline scripting should work on most cases in HTML email.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I'm not aware of any email client that doesn't strip all JS.

Comment: JS is not supported by any email clients that I know of.

Comment: Guys, many thanx for all responses!!

I tried to put a inline script in my html mail but does not worked!! =(

I will see these links right now!!!!

Comment: @Quentin
That is not 100% inaccurate. A few clients do have limited JS support (very limited) - but I will admit I did misread the title of the question. I thought OP was asking in reference to a solution on a webpage, not an HTML email. That is completely my oversight.